# Can I get a Tallinja card on arrival at Malta airport?

Tags: public-transport, tickets, buses, malta, tallinja-cards

I gather that as of summer 2015, Malta has introduced a stored-value card for use on buses, much along the lines of London's Oyster card or Hong Kong's Octopus card. The Maltese version is called a [Tallinja card](https://www.tallinja.com/).

Looking at the [bus fares table](https://www.tallinja.com/en/faq), a single journey on the bus is only 75c with a Tallinja card, vs €1.50 (winter) / €2 (summer) if bought with cash on the bus. So, it looks to deliver a decent enough saving to be worth getting for even short trips!

However, I can't seem to find anything on the [Tallinja card website](https://www.tallinja.com/) about being able to buy one on arrival at the airport. As an arriving tourist, is this possible, and if so how?

Comment: It appears that you can order it online and have it posted to you, but you have to pay the postage.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I doubt they'd be able to get it to me in time before I fly off to Malta in 3 days! That's why I was hoping to buy one at the airport, just before hopping on the bus from the airport to where we're staying

Comment: @drat Ended up booking a very cheap direct transfer via the hotel, so we didn't need to get one from the airport in the end, and the transfer was waiting for us so we didn't have time to go investigate buying one all the same

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Having arrived at Malta airport February 1, 2016, there was a booth (I think towards the right hand side from Arrivals) where I was able to purchase a Tallinja card for €21 for 7-days. The booth also accepts Amex cards.

This covers the whole of Malta and Gozo (Għawdex). Whether or not this can be topped-up I'm not sure.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is possible and it is very easy. [This webpage on publictransport.com.mt](https://www.publictransport.com.mt/en/where-to-buy-your-travel-card) (retrieved in June 2018) includes two sales points in **Malta International Airport**:

- Agenda Bookshop (Departures Hall),
- WHS Express (Arrivals Hall).

This latter in particular is only a few steps before the exit on the bus terminal, coming from Arrivals. Twice in the latest year I bought there my ticket or Tallinja card just before getting on the bus to Valletta or other destination.

Answer (score 7):

The other answers here are still correct, but also, there are now some [Tallinja card vending machines](https://www.publictransport.com.mt/en/our-sales-and-information-points-and-terminals) in the arrivals hall and by the bus stop itself. This is especially handy if you have an early or late flight and the human-staffed sales outlets are closed.