# Can two people share a 12-trip Tallinja card when traveling together in Malta?

Tags: public-transport, tickets, buses, malta, tallinja-cards

Looking at the [Maltese public transport page for non-personalised tickets](https://www.tallinja.com/en/bus-tickets-and-non-personalised-cards), following on from my earlier question on [Tallinja cards](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/59618/can-i-get-a-tallinja-card-on-arrival-at-malta-airport), I see that they offer a 12-trip card for €15.

I'm not sure if I'll need 12 trips on my upcoming trip, but I can see us getting through 6 trips each. So, sharing a single card would be good, if it's allowed, which I'm not sure it is.

Is it possible for two people to board with a single 12-trip non-personalised tallinja card, and both tap in / validate with it? (Using up 2 of the trips, of course!). Or is it impossible for multiple people to use trips from those at the same time, needing their own card if they're travelling together?

Answer (score 6):

Update 2023: This is not allowed. On the [Malta Public Transport website](https://www.publictransport.com.mt/en/12-day-journey-card) it says:

> This card can be used by a **single person** for 12 journeys on day
> routes, 6 journeys on Tallinja Direct Routes, Night Routes and other
> premium services, or else a mix of both.

This was also confirmed by their online support (enquiries@publictransport.com.mt) on June 27th 2023:

> Kindly nothe that the Twelve Single Day Journey Cards include twelve day trips or six night trips or six trips on TD routes.   **These cards cannot be shared.** These are easily bought from our ticket
> booths and cost €15. Any unused trips for Twelve Single Journey Cards
> are not refundable.

Comment: Confirmed with their official support over email, edited your answer to include their quote. Thank you for adding the answer!