# Purchasing monthly personalised Tallinja Cards

Tags: public-transport, tickets, fares, malta, tallinja-cards

My wife and I are U.K. citizens and will be visiting Malta for six weeks from 3rd March this year. We are booked into the Plaza Hotels in Sliema. Is it possible for us to purchase monthly personalised tallinja cards? If so how do we apply for them?

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/59618/can-i-get-a-tallinja-card-on-arrival-at-malta-airport

Answer (score 3):

You can [register for a Tallinja Card online](https://www.tallinja.com/en/register-now), using the official website. The card will then be shipped to your address. Otherwise you can collect an application form from the ticket booth, fill it in and hand it back to the booth. [There is one such booth at the airport.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/59618/can-i-get-a-tallinja-card-on-arrival-at-malta-airport)

Quoting from [the Tallinja FAQ](https://www.tallinja.com/en/faq):

> #### How can I obtain a tallinja card?
>
> One can easily apply for the tallinja card online at www.tallinja.com, by calling on 2122 2000, or else by collecting an application form from our ticket booth, filling it in, and leaving again at our ticket booth. No applications are accepted by mail. You will need to provide some form of identification like your Maltese or International Identity Card Number, Maltese or International Passport Number or Maltese Driving Licence number, together with your name, surname, date of birth, contact mobile number and email address. The mobile number and email address will be used to keep you updated with your application process. Registered postal charges for local deliveries are €1.14, whilst those for foreign deliveries are €6.00.

Once you have a card, you can top it up and purchase a monthly pass. Below is the FAQ on topping up:

> #### How can I top up the tallinja card?
>
> This can be done using the following options:
>
> - By visiting www.tallinja.com and paying by Credit/Debit Card;
> - By buying a top-up voucher from various outlets and topping up using your phone;
> - By visiting any MaltaPost Post Office and topping up in cash;
> - By visiting any of our outlets and topping up in cash;
> - By calling on 2122 2000 to top up by Credit/Debit Card.

[To date (Feb 2016) the monthly pass costs 26 EUR.](https://www.tallinja.com/en/faq)